# make div clip through parrent

Tags: html, css

I'm working through the [cssbattle.dev](https://cssbattle.dev/play/9) challenges to improve with CSS, and I'm stuck really close to the result on the 9 one. Can someone help me out?

[The Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LziYw.png)

My Code:

```css
  body {
    background:#222730;
    margin:0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .banner{
    background: #4CAAB3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 75px;
  }
  .center-box{
    position:relative;
    top: -50px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid 50px #222730;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .dot{
    position: absolute;
    background: #393E46;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 125px;
    left: 175px;    
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="center-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: background: inherit; to center-box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  .center-box{
    position:relative;
    top: -50px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid 50px #222730;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: inherit ;
        
  }
```